Accessing static file in flask app python
I've been making a simple website which runs an image classification model using keras on an image captured from the users webcam. At the moment, my model is saved in the static folder of my flask app. The problem is in the actual loading of the model. When I try to load the model (in the python file, app.py, which contains my flask app).
@app.route('/')
def init():
    
    model = load_model('/static/model/model.keras')
    return render_template('index.html')

it throws an error that the file could not be found.
I've tried using requests to load it and write it from github, which resulted in the same error.
I've also tried doing
@app.route('/cdn/<path:filename>')
def custom_static(filename):
    return send_from_directory('/static', filename)

and loading it from that, but the same error persists.

It looks like you have entered the path part of a URL where you actually need to use a path in the file system.

I have tried ./static/model/model.keras and it threw the same error as well. I'll double check it now.

You will have to know where you stored the file. Then use the full path to prevent any surprises.

Yep, no dice:
@app.route('/')
def init():
    
    model = load_model('./static/model/model.keras')
    return render_template('index.html')


The absolute path to the configured static folder can be accessed via app.static_folder .

This question is similar to: How to serve static files in Flask. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
